# PHP array loop print in pairs

Tags: php, arrays

The array

```
Array ( [0] =>
CLG
0%
[1] =>
TSM
0%
[2] =>
7sway
10%
[3] =>
Nostalgie
90%
[4] => 
K1CK.pt
9%
[5] =>
E-Frag
91%
[6] =>
HR
86%
```

So I want to print the elements of this array into the same div by using the for loop. I want to print 2 array parts into the same element

The imageined output

```
<div>
CLG
0%
TSM
0%
</div>

<div>
7sway
10%
Nostalgie
90%
</div>
```

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

I think the poster messed up the encoding and this code is enough to do what he expects:

```
$arr = array("CLG 0%", "TSM 0%", "7sway 10%", "Nostalgie 90%", "K1CK.pt 9%", "E-Frag 91%", "HR 86%");

for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($arr); $i++) {
    if ($i % 2 === 0) {
        echo '<div>' . $arr[$i] . ' ';
    } else {
        echo $arr[$i] . '</div>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use array_chunk to make pairs

```
foreach (array_chunk($arr,2) as $i)
   echo '<div>' . implode('', $i) . '</div>';
```